# An application of isomorphism theorem for quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

I am working on a proof that shows principal ideal $(2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$ is maximal. Let us first say that $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = \delta $ in short. The book proves the claim by showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\delta]/(2)$ is a field. First,

$\mathbb{Z}[\delta] \cong \mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^2 -y-1)$ which makes sense since $y^2 -y-1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\delta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, $\mathbb{Z}[\delta] /(2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^2 -y-1))/ (2)$ that is still okay. After that, it goes like below and I need help to understand the rest:

$$\mathbb{Z}[\delta] /(2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^2 -y-1))/ (2) \cong \mathbb{Z}[y]/(2,y^2 -y-1) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})[y]/(y^2-y-1).$$ - How?

"$y^2-y-1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$ so it is irreducible and the quotient is a domain." - Yes.

"Hence, $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})[y]/(y^2-y-1)$ is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F_4}$ with four elements " -How? Is the quotient finite?

"Thus, $(2)$ is a maximal ideal."

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1)  A finite domain is a field.

2) $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[y]/(p(y))$, where p(y) is polynomial of degree $d$ is a $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$-vector space of dimension $d$, hence it has $2^d$ elements.

Some more details to justify the equivalences above:

If $I, J$ are ideals of a ring $R$, the ideal generated by $J$ in $R/I$ is $\;J\cdot R/I=(I+J)/I$, so
$$(R/I)\big/J\cdot R/I=(R/I)\Big/\big((I+J)/I\big)\simeq R/(I+J).$$

For the last isomorphism, you can tensor the short exact sequence 
$$0\longrightarrow (y^2-y-1)\longrightarrow \mathbf Z[y]\longrightarrow \mathbf Z[y]/(Y^2-y-1)\longrightarrow0$$
by $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, and use that for polynomial rings
$$R[y]\otimes_R R/I\simeq R[y]/IR[y]\simeq R/I[y].$$

Comment: Okay, I understand that part. Could you help me with the isomorphism equivalences above?

Comment: I'd be happy to help more, but I thought I answered your question. Could you explain what remains a problem for you?

Comment: I mean I need help on $\mathbb{Z}[\delta] /(2) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^2 -y-1))/ (2) \cong \mathbb{Z}[y]/(2,y^2 -y-1) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})[y]/(y^2-y-1)$ part too

Comment: I showed that given ideals $I=(a), J=(b) $, $ (a,b)=I+J $ but still can not see the equivalences above.

Comment: I've added some details. Is that clearer?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not see why the ideal generated by $J$ in $R/I$ is $\;J\cdot R/I=(I+J)/I$ and do not know how to apply tensor product by $Z/2Z$...

Comment: The ideal generated by $J$ is the set of congruence classes $\{j+I\mid j\in J\}$, so it should be obvious that it is $J+I$. Isn't it the case? For the other question, didn't you study the tensor product?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I understood my first question. I have studied tensor products but have not checked for a while.